# Use npm command in a repo that uses pnpm

Tags: javascript, npm, pnpm

I have a project that uses npm but I want to migrate to pnpm.
After `pnpm import && rm package-lock.json && pnpm i --frozen-lockfile --shamefully-hoist` everything installs smoothly, app runs, tests pass.
Is there any drawback / potential issue to still run everything (except the install, of course) e.g. `npm run test`, `npm run build` etc. with npm? Not seeing any problem currently.
Asking because changing the CI/CD pipelines would be quite some effort that I would like to postpone

Answer (score 2):

If you are using scripts in `package.json` that contain multiple steps, like `

```json
{
  ...
  "scripts": {
    "build": "pnpm run foo && pnpm run bar"`
  }
  ...
}
```

then you will need to ensure pnpm is installed.

Other than that, it does not matter if you use `npm run` and `pnpm run` to execute the scripts, except for the minor difference [documented on `pnpm run` page](https://pnpm.io/cli/run#differences-with-npm-run):

> By default, pnpm doesn't run arbitrary `pre` and `post` hooks for user-defined scripts (such as `prestart`). This behavior, inherited from npm, caused scripts to be implicit rather than explicit, obfuscating the execution flow. It also led to surprising executions with `pnpm serve` also running `pnpm preserve`.
>
> If for some reason you need the pre/post scripts behavior of npm, use the `enable-pre-post-scripts` option.

You can enable this option by running `pnpm config set enable-pre-post-scripts true`, it will store the setting into `~/.config/pnpm/rc`.